# Detect hardware headphone presses in mac

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

This question is concerning the code from this question: [Detect headphone button presses in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772976/detect-headphone-button-presses-in-os-x)

Their answer was marked correct, however I couldn't get their code to work (this may be because of my lack of knowledge of objective-c). I followed their instructions, and modified three files. This is what I have tried (I have also looked at Apple's IOKit documentation and could not find any headphone hardware button documentation):

AwesomeClass.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#include "KeyboardPaneController.h"

@interface AwesomeClass : KeyboardPaneController
+ (NSArray *) allKeyboards;
- (void) initKeyboardElements: (NSArray *) elements;
- (void) ddhidQueueHasEvents: (DDHidQueue *) hidQueue;
@end
```

AwesomeClass.m

```
#import "AwesomeClass.h"
#import "DDHidLib.h"

@implementation AwesomeClass

+ (NSArray *) allKeyboards;
{
    NSArray *array = [DDHidDevice allDevicesMatchingUsagePage: kHIDPage_Consumer
                                                      usageId: kHIDUsage_GD_Pointer
                                                    withClass: self
                                            skipZeroLocations: NO];

    //Only return "Apple Mikey HID Driver", if not found, return nil.
    for (DDHidDevice *device in array) {
        if ([[device productName] isEqualToString:@"Apple Mikey HID Driver"]) {
            return [NSArray arrayWithObject:device];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void) initKeyboardElements: (NSArray *) elements;
{
    NSEnumerator * e = [elements objectEnumerator];
    DDHidElement * element;
    while (element = [e nextObject])
    {
        unsigned usagePage = [[element usage] usagePage];
        unsigned usageId = [[element usage] usageId];
        if (usagePage == kHIDPage_GenericDesktop)
        {
            if ((usageId >= 0x89) && (usageId <= 0x8D))
            {
                [mKeyElements addObject: element];
            }
        }
        NSArray * subElements = [element elements];
        if (subElements != nil)
            [self initKeyboardElements: subElements];
    }
}

- (void) ddhidQueueHasEvents: (DDHidQueue *) hidQueue;
{
    DDHidEvent * event;
    while ((event = [hidQueue nextEvent]))
    {
        DDHidElement * element = [self elementForCookie: [event elementCookie]];
        unsigned usageId = [[element usage] usageId];
        SInt32 value = [event value];
        if (value == 1)
            [self ddhidKeyboard: self keyDown: usageId];
    }
}
@end
```

...as well as modifying one line in KeyboardPaneController.m (that was shown in the instructions). Due to the lack of documentation on the framework, it's really difficult to find an answer (the poster has been offline for more than a year, so I'm assuming I probably won't get a response back). The code was tested on lion, and I have mountain lion so that might be the issue.

I know that this is definitely possible to implement because iTunes is very responsive to my headphone-button-presses (which is a bit of a nuance). I'd like to be able to control Spotify with the buttons on my headphones, rather than iTunes.

Comment: Is `+allKeyboards` returning `nil` or did it find something? Have you tried logging the device product names to see if maybe there's a name which looks promising but is different than the one expected by that code? (In general, you need to be more clear about how this code is failing.)

Comment: I know that allKeyboards did not return the headphones, or the sound card. However, I will see exactly what allKeyboards is returning and post the results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A test shows it isn't implemented as a keyboard anymore:

```
    id array = [[DDHidDevice allDevices] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"productName == \"Apple Mikey HID Driver\""]];
    DDHidDevice *mic = [array count] ? [array objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    // it isn't a keyboard
    NSLog(@"%@", mic.primaryUsage);
    assert(mic.usage==1 && mic.usagePage==12);
```

You can't treat it like a HIDKeyboard either  (tried, it doesn't send key presses), nor a HIDMouse or HID Joystick.

I dug into the HIDQueue class and checked if the mikey fires any low level events and it does fire low level events! The `queueCallbackFunction` is called for presses (if you don't filter the queue for specific events. To filter it, see `initWithKeyboardEvents` in DDHidKeyboard.

Now all you have to do is map the low level events to the correct buttons and you are done. Maybe wrap it all in a nice class too. Here's a sample of the class and relevant code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDHidLib).

Comment: it is not specific to one headphone BUT right now there is APPLE_MIC_ONLY 1 defined. why? because IOKit doesnt really differntiate between an apple remote or a mic or even a trackpad

Comment: one could improve this detection algorithm but I only have the apple mic to test with -- anyway it is all in the method `allMikeys`

Comment: Does it also apply to Bluetooth devices?