# C++ detect Apple headphone buttons on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi

**BACKGROUND INFORMATION:**

I've been trying to detect a button click from Apple headphone. The headphone is connected to MacBook Pro that is running Windows. Its not virtual machine. It is running windows normally with a complete windows driver from Apple through Boot Camp.

The headphone is a standard Apple headphone consisted of three buttons: a volume up, volume down, middle buttons and a Mic.

When I am using Mac Os, If the volume up button is presses on the ear phone, Mac Os would increase its volume by one. It also decreases its volume when the  voulume down button is pressed on the ear phone.

Standard ear/headphone uses ***three*** conductive pins to **receive(L/R speakers only) signals** while the apple version is using ***four*** conductive pins to **receive(L/R speakers) and send(buttons) signals**. This headphone was made for iPhone but I was surprised when it worked on Mac Os.

This made me believe that the MacBook Pro hardware is built to support this ***four*** conductive pins earphone. It works on Mac Os but **NOT** on Windows. My goal is to develop a tiny software that will allow the apple headphone to function on Windows running on Apple hardware.

I know how to increase Windows volume using C++ and Win32 API but I am stuck on the part where I actually have to detect the button click from the headphone.

**QUESTION:**

**1**) what ways can I detect the Input(button clicks) from the headphone?

It looks like this person here was able to read it. He only did it while running on Mac Os
[Detect hardware headphone presses in mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398237/detect-hardware-headphone-presses-in-mac)

**2**) If I compile the code this person got working on Mac OS as a DLL file and then call the function while running Windows, will it work?

**3**) Do I need to make my own driver to get this to work?

4) The code below is from the link I posted above. What windows API function, class is equivelent to the follwoing Mac Os code below?

```
 id array = [[DDHidDevice allDevices] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"productName == \"Apple Mikey HID Driver\""]];
    DDHidDevice *mic = [array count] ? [array objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    // it isn't a keyboard
    NSLog(@"%@", mic.primaryUsage);
    assert(mic.usage==1 && mic.usagePage==12);
```

**THINGS I'VE TRIED:**

**1**) I tried using `GetLastInputInfo()` with `LASTINPUTINFO` from Windows API to sniff any hardware input but failed miserably. It worked on keyboard and mouse but nothing else.

**2**) I also tried to use `RAWINPUTDEVICE` to read a low level input from hardware but it only worked on keyboards, mouse and joystick input. It didn't detect the headphone button press.

I am running out of ideas. Anyone got any solution?

**NOTE: This is not a duplicate question as I am asking how to do this on Windows not Mac.**

Comment: You're probably going to have to write your own driver to do this. Since the buttons don't control the volume in Windows/Boot Camp already, it's likely that Apple just re-bundled the base Windows driver for the audio chip in your MacBook Pro - which doesn't know anything about the hardware Apple added for their headphone serial protocol.

Comment: You probably will find something looking at the source of non-official drivers (i.e. hackintosh stuff ;) ... if you find something please share with us...

Comment: Any updates?

At least the pause/resume button encoding seems to be the same for headphones for e.g. Android as well and people have interest in that: http://superuser.com/questions/805287/wired-headphone-buttons-on-windows

Comment: @phk Nahh. No update. Gave up long time ago.